# Why can I access variables that are conditionally defined outside of function in Python?

Tags: python

I am coming from C, C++, and Java background. So I am curious to know why the following Python code works:

```
def f1():
    print(xy)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello")
    xy = 34
    f1()
```

It prints:

```
Hello
34
```

How can I access `xy` in function `f1`? `xy` is not defined inside `f1` also, `xy` is defined in a conditional block of `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: Python does not have enclosing scopes that you are used to in `C++`. At the line `xy = 34`, the variable `xy` is entered into the local module scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Global Variables**
>
> In Python, a variable declared outside of the function or in global
>   scope is known as global variable. This means, global variable can be
>   accessed inside or outside of the function.

Comment: That is fine, I can understand it as a global variable. What I didn't understand is, that `xy` variable has been defined in an `if` condition. How can an `if` condition variable be accessed outside its block?

Comment: If statement is not a function, variables declared in a function are local variables, and everything declared outside of the function are globals

Answer (score 0):

While in many or most other programming languages variables are treated as global if not otherwise declared, Python deals with variables the other way around. They are local, if not otherwise declared.

```
def f():
   print(x)
x = "Something"
f()
```

This prints "Something"

Comment: But `x` is global in your example